# Eureka Server Health Not Running

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I updated a eureka server from Camdem.R3 to Flinchley.RC1 lately. There were a lot of changes in the settings.

On Camden.R3, without doing any additional settings the console link to the health check would work. For Flinchley.RC1 the health check would give a 404 response. I am trying to read the latest settings in Flinchley document but it only states how to check the health. Is there a way to find out if the client really ran the health check context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several research, I found out that the spring boot actuator specs was changed for 2.0. For Camden.R3 which is compatible with spring boot 1.X, all actuators starts in the base context. While Flinchley.RC1 which is compatible with spring boot 2.0 all context requires a context prefix of "/actuator".

Spring Boot 1.X actuator:

- All of the actuator endpoints "sub sites" are turned on by default.
- Health actuator would give a more detailed information in its
  response
- The actuator starts on base context of Eureka Client Site (e.g. localhost:8080/health)

Spring Boot 2.0 actuator:

- Only the health and info are turned on by default.
- Health actuator would give a simple answer of UP / DOWN. To show others you need to set them in configuration.
- All actuator must have the endpoint prefix in URL. The default prefix
  is "actuator" (e.g. http://localhost:8080/actuator/health)

See the following sites for more details:

- [Spring Boot Actuator](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) (very detailed explanation)
- [Spring Boot Actuator 1.X Official Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints)
- [Spring Boot Actuator 2.0 Official Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/actuator-api/html/)